# Authorize specific nodes - Allow connections from a sub-node "Dave"

Tags: pallet, substrate-node-template

I am following the Get Started tutorials "Authorize specific nodes". I have allowed the connection from the sub-node "Dave" to the parent node "Charlie", but it seems that the sub-node "Dave" is not connected to "Charlie".
[image]
I can see from the Charlie's node that showing there is a 3 peers after submit add connection transaction, but just only in the next block it turned back to 2 peers. And in the Dave's node, it always shows 0 peers. Any suggestions for that? Thank you!

Charlie's Node

```
2022-09-24 19:47:12 ✨ Imported #160 (0xbbac…7a03)    
2022-09-24 19:47:16  Idle (3 peers), best: #160 (0xbbac…7a03), finalized #158 (0x3070…d509), ⬇ 2.6kiB/s ⬆ 3.4kiB/s    
2022-09-24 19:47:18 ✨ Imported #161 (0xd746…7a88)    
2022-09-24 19:47:21  Idle (2 peers), best: #161 (0xd746…7a88), finalized #159 (0x41c4…cdfe), ⬇ 1.4kiB/s ⬆ 1.3kiB/s
```

Comment: didn't quite understand your issue, can you please explain it a little bit more

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hi, updated the post. I followed the tutorials to add the sub-node Dave connection to the parent node Charlie, but it doesn't work. Not sure if there is any steps missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After this last step: Allow connections to the sub-node yo have to stop Dave node, and then restart it:

```
./target/release/node-template \
--chain=local \
--base-path /tmp/validator4 \
--name dave \
--node-key=a99331ff4f0e0a0434a6263da0a5823ea3afcfffe590c9f3014e6cf620f2b19a \
--port 30336 \
--ws-port 9947 \
--offchain-worker always
```

You should see now it connected in Charlie's node:

```
2022-09-26 10:31:30  Idle (2 peers), best: #123 (0x447b…0998), finalized #120 (0x5985…a18c), ⬇ 1.4kiB/s ⬆ 1.3kiB/s    
2022-09-26 10:31:35  Idle (3 peers), best: #123 (0x447b…0998), finalized #121 (0xa6d6…b261), ⬇ 2.2kiB/s ⬆ 5.0kiB/s    
2022-09-26 10:31:36 ✨ Imported #124 (0x19f9…4eb4)    
2022-09-26 10:31:40  Idle (3 peers), best: #124 (0x19f9…4eb4), finalized #122 (0x277f…14b0), ⬇ 1.9kiB/s ⬆ 2.1kiB/s
```

And in Dave's node:

```
2022-09-26 10:31:36 ✨ Imported #124 (0x19f9…4eb4)    
2022-09-26 10:31:39  Idle (1 peers), best: #124 (0x19f9…4eb4), finalized #122 (0x277f…14b0), ⬇ 4.9kiB/s ⬆ 1.6kiB/s
```

Comment: Hi Alex, I have tried to restart the node, but it stills showed 0 peer in Dave’s node. Then I tried to remove all the tmp files, and redo all the steps to authorise Charlie’s and Dave’s node, but the result is the same.

Comment: And if you try to do the: Allow connections to the sub-node step without run the Dave node, and run it after. Still showing 0?

Comment: Thanks Alex. I tried again and it works now. Maybe I got some mistakes on one of the steps.

Comment: Great that it worked! Not sure but I think the node has to be restarted after the extrinsics, will check again and review the documentation